# Bypassing TSQL CONTAINS filtering

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, full-text-search, contains

Is there a best practice for bypassing fulltext filtering of resultset, if a search text not specified? What I do now is:

```
SELECT * FROM items
WHERE @search='all' OR CONTAINS(*,@search)
```

But I wonder if there is a more elegant way?

Comment: On what condition do u want to search for all or CONTAINS(*,@search). Do you have any specific situation ?

Comment: The condition when i want all rows returned is when the user has not specified any search string. And when the serch string is specified - i want the result set filtered by CONTAINS

Answer (score 0):

Your example is the most *elegant* way of writing the query. However you should really look at the execution plan to see if this is the most *performant* approach.

You may want to consider writing the query like this to ensure SQL Server isn't evaluating the CONTAINS operator when it isn't necessary.

```
if (@search = 'all')
    SELECT * FROM items
else
    SELECT * FROM items
    WHERE CONTAINS(*,@search)
```

Comment: isn't mssql query optimizer capable of eliminating unnecessary tests after the well-defined TRUE OR?

Comment: Why i dont want a separate select for the case when @search is 'all' is because i have this piece inside a JOIN of several fulll-text subqueries. so if i split them all - there will be too many possible combinations ( N^2, for 3 joined subquries gives 9 execution branches )

Comment: It's likely that the OR will short circuit, I'm just recommending that you be extra safe. Check out the execution plan regardless.

Comment: I checked the execution plan, and it clearly shows that when @search is 'all' - there is no fulltext search in the plan (otherwise it is there)